# How to write column headers to excel export as displayed in visual if you pick aggregate function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I need suggestions on how to write Column headers to excel export file as Column names only without aggregate function. Suppose if It's Average It exports to excel as AverageColumnName or if Count It exports as CountColumnName, instead I just Need ColumnName.

For instance if my visual has Scores for header and I 'm doing average on values the Excel Export shows as header as Average_of_Scores instead of just Scores.
Example: Current output is
EmpName         Week End Date        Average of Scores
Anderson, David 10/17/2020                      4.2

Desired output
EmpName           Week End Date     Scores
Anderson, David 10/17/2020              4.2

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide also example input and desired output. It is difficult to understand from your description.

Comment: For instance if my visual shows ColumnName's as Scores1  for header and I 'm doing average on values the Excel Export shows as header as Average_of_Scores instead of just Scores.    EmpName Week End Date Average of Score
Anderson, David 10/17/2020 0:00 4